# Solving inequality with parameter

Tags: inequality

Find parameter $a$ for which solution of inequality $7(x+3) < -2(ax + 3)$ is $x \in (3, \infty)$

I found that $a < - \frac{7x + 27}{2x}$, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Solve for $x$ instead of $α$. Then you will get a condition for $α$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better idea is to solve for $x$:
$$ (7+2a)x < -21-6 = -27. $$
If $7+2a>0$, dividing gives an inequality of the form $x<\cdots$, which we don't want. If $7+2a<0$, dividing by it reverses the sense of the inequality, so
$$ x > \frac{-27}{7+2a}. $$
You're looking for this to be satisfied by all $x>3$, so therefore the right-hand side must be equal to $3$ (if it isn't, the inequality we get will not be $x>3$...). Hence,
$$ 3=\frac{-27}{7+2a}, $$
which you can solve to find $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The general strategy when you have a parameter is trying to formally solve the inequation (or whatever) including the parameter in your computations.

Then, the inequation is:
$$\begin{align}
7\,(x+3) &<-2\,(a\,x+3) \\
(7+2\,a)\, x &< -27
\end{align}$$
Since the result you wish to obtain is $x>3$, then it must be $7+2\,a<0$, so that dividing both sides, you obtain:
$$x>\frac{-27}{7+2\,a}$$
Then you get the desired result if
$$\frac{-27}{7+2\,a}=3$$
or
$$a=-8$$